# Copying entire contents of a server

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I need to copy the whole contents of a linux server, but I'm not sure how to do it recursively.

I have a migration script to run on the server itself, but it won't run because the disc is full, so I need something I can run remotely which just gets everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I need to copy the whole contents of a linux server, but I'm not sure how to do it recursively.**

How about

```
scp -r root@remotebox:/ your_local_copy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rsync -hxDPavil -H --stats --delete / remote:/backup/
```

this will copy everything (permissions, owners, timestamps, devices, sockets, hardlinks etc). It will also delete stuff that no longer exists in source. (note that `-x` indicates to only copy files within the same mountpoint)

If you want to preserve owners but the receiving end is not on the same domain, use `--numeric-ids`

To automate incremental backup w/snapshots, look at rdiff-backup or rsnapshot.

Also, gnu tar is highly underrated

sudo tar cpf /  | ssh remote 'cd /backup && tar xv'

Comment: Thanks. I might try something like this next time, but I already followed the other suggestion.